# Facing issue regarding data loss from database on magento235p1 when disable extension & reenabling it

Tags: database

There is data in my table as you can see in below image
[image]

when i disable the extension from command line & reenable it the data is getting remove from database as i attached the picture below
[image]

here is my database picture
[image]

here is my db_schema.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
   <table name="budd_vendor_category" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Vendor Category">
      <column xsi:type="smallint" name="id" padding="6" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="ID" />
      <column xsi:type="varchar" name="category" nullable="false" length="50" comment="Category" />
      <column xsi:type="int" name="parent_id" nullable="false" padding="6" comment="Parent" identity="false" />
      <column xsi:type="varchar" name="description" nullable="true" length="255" comment="Descrition" />
      <column xsi:type="tinyint" name="status" padding="6" nullable="false" default="1" comment="Status" />
      <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
         <column name="id" />
      </constraint>
   </table>
    <table name="marketplace_userdata" resource="default" engine="innodb">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="category_id" padding="6" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="false"
                 comment="Category Id"/>
    </table>
     <table name="marketplace_seller_paypal" resource="default" engine="innodb">
      <column xsi:type="smallint" name="id" padding="6" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="ID" />
      <column xsi:type="varchar" name="username" nullable="false" length="50" comment="User name" />
      <column xsi:type="varchar" name="password" nullable="false" length="100" comment="password"  />
      <column xsi:type="varchar" name="signature" nullable="false" length="400" comment="Signature" />
      <column xsi:type="int" name="sellerid" nullable="false" padding="6" comment="Seller Id" />
      <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
         <column name="id" />
      </constraint>
    </table>
    
     <table name="marketplace_subscription_square" resource="default" engine="innodb">
      <column xsi:type="smallint" name="id" padding="6" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="ID" />
      <column xsi:type="int" name="customer_id" nullable="false" padding="6" comment="Customer id" />
      <column xsi:type="int" name="isseller" nullable="false" padding="2" comment="Is Seller"  />
      <column xsi:type="varchar" name="transaction_id" nullable="false" length="400" comment="Transaction Id" />
      <!-- <column xsi:type="varchar" name="transactionId" nullable="false" length="400" comment="Transaction Id" /> -->
      <column xsi:type="int" name="plan_id" nullable="false" padding="6" comment="Plan Id" />
       <column xsi:type="int" name="period" nullable="false" padding="6" comment="Period" />
      <column xsi:type="decimal" name="amount" nullable="false" scale="4" precision="12" default="0.0000" unsigned="false" comment="Amount" />
      <column xsi:type="timestamp" name="createAt" nullable="false"  comment="Created At" />
      <column xsi:type="varchar" name="name" nullable="false" length="100" comment="Name on card" />
      <column xsi:type="varchar" name="bussines_name" nullable="false" length="100" comment="Bussiness Name" />
      <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
         <column name="id" />
      </constraint>
    </table>    
</schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my db_schema.xml

```
<!-- Definition for the 'budd_vendor_category' table -->
<table name="budd_vendor_category" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Vendor Category">
    <column xsi:type="smallint" name="id" padding="6" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="ID" />
    <column xsi:type="varchar" name="category" nullable="false" length="50" comment="Category" />
    <column xsi:type="int" name="parent_id" nullable="false" padding="6" comment="Parent" identity="false" />
    <column xsi:type="varchar" name="description" nullable="true" length="255" comment="Description" />
    <column xsi:type="tinyint" name="status" padding="6" nullable="false" default="1" comment="Status" />
    <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
        <column name="id" />
    </constraint>
</table>

<!-- Definition for the 'marketplace_userdata' table -->
<table name="marketplace_userdata" resource="default" engine="innodb">
    <column xsi:type="int" name="category_id" padding="6" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="false"
        comment="Category Id"/>
</table>

<!-- Definition for the 'marketplace_seller_paypal' table -->
<table name="marketplace_seller_paypal" resource="default" engine="innodb">
    <column xsi:type="smallint" name="id" padding="6" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="ID" />
    <column xsi:type="varchar" name="username" nullable="false" length="50" comment="User name" />
    <column xsi:type="varchar" name="password" nullable="false" length="100" comment="Password" />
    <column xsi:type="varchar" name="signature" nullable="false" length="400" comment="Signature" />
    <column xsi:type="int" name="sellerid" nullable="false" padding="6" comment="Seller Id" />
    <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
        <column name="id" />
    </constraint>
</table>

<!-- Definition for the 'marketplace_subscription_square' table -->
<table name="marketplace_subscription_square" resource="default" engine="innodb">
    <column xsi:type="smallint" name="id" padding="6" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="ID" />
    <column xsi:type="int" name="customer_id" nullable="false" padding="6" comment="Customer id" />
    <column xsi:type="int" name="isseller" nullable="false" padding="2" comment="Is Seller"  />
    <column xsi:type="varchar" name="transaction_id" nullable="false" length="400" comment="Transaction Id" />
    <column xsi:type="int" name="plan_id" nullable="false" padding="6" comment="Plan Id" />
    <column xsi:type="int" name="period" nullable="false" padding="6" comment="Period" />
    <column xsi:type="decimal" name="amount" nullable="false" scale="4" precision="12" default="0.0000" unsigned="false" comment="Amount" />
    <column xsi:type="timestamp" name="createdAt" nullable="false"  comment="Created At" />
    <column xsi:type="varchar" name="name" nullable="false" length="100" comment="Name on card" />
    <column xsi:type="varchar" name="business_name" nullable="false" length="100" comment="Business Name" />
    <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
        <column name="id" />
    </constraint>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add a file in a question section. This is an answer section.

Answer (score 0):

DB schema removes tables after disabling the extension.

Please run the setup upgrade command with the **--safe-mode=1** parameter after disabling the module. It will take a backup of the disabled module's tables.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade --safe-mode=1
```

Please run the setup upgrade command with the **--data-restore=1** parameter after re-enabling the disabled module. It will restore the data.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade --data-restore=1
```

This solution works for you.